# Disable checklistbox checkbox on click but not from code behind

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I am creating a winforms application with a Checkedlistbox which contains some names. What i need is for the checkboxes to be disabled from being checked by clicking, but still be checkable from the code.

I tried setting the `.CheckOnClick` to false, but then the checkbox still checks on the second click.

I've tried the solution from the following question:
[How to disable a checkbox in a checkedlistbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368618/how-to-disable-a-checkbox-in-a-checkedlistbox)
But this resulted in disabling the ability of checking from the code as well..

Disabling the entire box is not an option, this will disable all events including the selecting and doublemouseclick which are crucial in my application.

Anyone that knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, what you need to do is handle the ItemCheck event for your CheckedListBox, like so:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
}
```

If you want to change the state of a checkbox in code, then you will have to remove the event handle temporarily:

```
checkedListBox1.ItemCheck -= checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(1, true);
checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
```

It's not elegant, but it is a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Enabled` property to `False`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled.aspx