# How to disable a checkedboxlist item in a VB form in VS

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable a checkbox in a checkedlistbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368618/how-to-disable-a-checkbox-in-a-checkedlistbox)

I'm looking at trying to disable a checkboxlist item if another item is checked. The handling of this is easy however I'm struggling on actually disabling a particular item. There seems to be no enabled function in Items property so I'm unsure how to disable specific items.

```
If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked("0") = True Or 
       CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked("1") = True Then
                CheckedListBox1.Items(0).enabled=false
    ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked("0") = false AND 
       CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked("1") = false Then
        CheckedListBox1.Items(0).enabled=true
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: also: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/097d6baa-f924-45eb-8d64-f5baacf110f0 and http://www.dotnettechy.com/problem-solutions/disabling-an-item-in-a-checkedlistbox-c-winform-10.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this:

```
     Private Sub checkbox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles checkbox1.CheckedChanged

    If checkbox1.Focused = True Then
        checkbox1.Checked = True
    End If
    checkbox2.Checked = False
    checkbox3.Checked = False
    checkbox4.Checked = False
    checkbox5.Checked = False
    checkbox6.Checked = False
End Sub
```

and switch on every checkbox. Next will be checkbox2 in de checkbox 2 Sub.

Comment: This is for checkboxes rather than checkboxlists, however I've found it can't be done with checkbox lists so i've changed to checkboxes and put in a panel and used your method

Comment: Oh sorry did not read correctly then. I will look into it when i get some more time