# Disable an item in CheckListBox in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have code here but it only populates items in checklistbox.

```
Dim lst As New List(Of String) From {dtr.GetInt32("fps_pump_id")}

Do
    For Each items As String In lst
       y = dtr.GetInt32("fps_pump_id") 
       PumpStation.CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(y & " [" & items & "]")
       PumpStation.CheckedListBox1.Items(y).Enabled = False 'this line won't work
    Next
    x += 1
Loop Until x = ps_table.Rows.Count
```

`dtr.getIn32("fps_pump_id")` is a pre-loaded `MySqlDataReader` that I used to fetch data from my local database.

Comment: I don't know how well you understand C#, but I found this answer to be quite helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31370469

Answer (score 0):

You can add items in checkbox as:

```
CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(New ListItem With {.Text = y & " [" & items & "]", .Value = y, .Enabled = False})
```

Comment: What's the ListItem for?

Comment: ListItem represents ITEM in List/row. 
Here ListItem contains 4 objects: 
1. Text : displays on screen as checkbox label
2. Value : value of checkboxitem
3. Enabled : true/false. Default is true
4. Selected: true/false. Default is false

Comment: I think that `ListItem` that you're talking about is from ASP.NET or perhaps C#,
coz the parameters on Add() consists only of (text, boolean). In this case, the boolean serves as a "flag" if the newly added item on CheckListBox will be loaded as Checked or Unchecked

Comment: @kendev : C# is equal to VB.NET in the sense of what controls/objects you can use, however you are correct about that what the answer suggests is for ASP.NET. I have edited your question to include the `winforms` tag (_Windows Forms_, or _WinForms_ for short), which I suppose is the technology you're using. It should help avoid some confusion/uncertainty. :)